# Consultar cual es el auto mas vendido

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, heidisql

Tengo 3 tablas

Clientes: IdClien Nombre Sexo FechaNac

Productos: IdProd Marca Modelo Precio

Ventas IdVentas IdClien1 IdProd1 Fechavta

Tengo este código hasta ahora

```
Select max(IdProd) as MasVendido from Ventas
      Inner Join Productos on Productos.IdProf = ventas.IdProd1
```

Pero me da el nombre del primer auto que tengo registrado, no el que se ha vendido más.

Comment: Tienes que relacionar la tabla productos con la tabla ventas tomando como referencia idprod = idprod1 puedes ver estos ejemplos https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/hosting/cuestiones-tecnicas/inner-join/

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], por favor agrega lo que trataste o investigaste y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Y qué problema tiene ese código? (Aparte de que es select y no selec) ;)

Comment: Gracias, el problema que tiene es que,  me da el primer nombre de auto que registre y no me da el auto mas vendido

Comment: Porque le estas aplicando el max al ID del producto, no a la suma de ventas por producto

Comment: muestra el producto que mas se repite en la tabla de ventas. select * from Productos as p where p.IdProf  = (select max(v.IdProd) from Ventas as v)

Answer (score 0):

Aún te quedan un par de pasos: agrupar y contar, para quedarte con el máximo.

```
SELECT * FROM Productos
  JOIN (
    SELECT IdProd1,COUNT(*) n
      FROM Ventas
      GROUP BY IdProd1
      ORDER BY n DESC
      LIMIT 1  
  ) c1 ON IdProd1=IdProd;
```

Otra opción, para evitar la ordenación, sería:

```
SELECT * FROM Productos
  WHERE IdProd IN (
    SELECT IdProd1
      FROM Ventas
      GROUP BY IdProd1
      HAVING COUNT(*)=(
        SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
            SELECT IdProd1,COUNT(*) n
              FROM Ventas
              GROUP BY IdProd1  
          ) c1  
      )  
  );
```

Te paso el dataset que necesitarás para realizar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE Productos(
  IdProd int,
  Marca varchar(15),
  Modelo varchar(15),
  Precio float
  );
CREATE TABLE Ventas(
  IdVentas int,
  IdClien1 int,
  IdProd1 int,
  Fechavta date
  );
```

Te recomiendo dejar el `JOIN` para el final, como no lo necesitas hasta entonces, procesarás menos cantidad de información. No te hace falta combinar todos los registros de `Productos` para quedarte finalmente con uno.